# When do you get your first spy?

Tags: civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I am halfway through the medievil era. I am most of the way through researching Physics.

I just recruited a spy. It was not via building a wonder.

What triggers my first spy to be recruited?

Comment: You might also be interested in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75291/how-do-i-obtain-more-spies).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When any player enters the Renaissance Era, each player gets their first spy. Thus, an AI must have researched a tech that put them into the Renaissance era.